# Using session id's to grab data

Tags: php

I've been working on a project for a few weeks where a user chooses a set of ingredients and it pulls out the recipes that have them ingredients in, but now I have a page that displays the recipes and I want the user to be able to click on a specific recipe and be directed to a page that displays that recipe and it's instructions.

Would I need to use a session id?

This displays the results and the buttons that must be pressed to get to the recipes instructions page.
[image]

This is the page that you are directed to and it will display the recipe image, name, ingredients and instructions.

[image]

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $ingredient1 = mysql_real_escape_String ($_POST['dropdown1']);
    $ingredient2 = mysql_real_escape_String ($_POST['dropdown2']);
    $ingredient3 = mysql_real_escape_String ($_POST['dropdown3']);


    $recipes = mysql_query("
        SELECT DISTINCT `name`, `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, `image`, `reference`
        FROM `recipe` r
        INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
        ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
        WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (".$ingredient1.",".$ingredient2.",".$ingredient3.")
    ");

    while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {

        echo '<section id="row">';
        echo '<br />';
        echo $recipe['name'].'<br />'; 
        echo '<br />';
        echo "<img src=\"{$recipe['image']}\" height=100 width=100 /><br />";
        echo '<form action="recipe.php">';
        echo '<input id="search" name="Look" type="Submit" value="Look" >';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'You will Need: ';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '</section>';

        //echo 'Step 1: ';
        //echo $recipe['step1'].'<br />';
        //echo '<br />';
        //echo 'Step 2: ';
        //echo $recipe['step2'].'<br />';
        //echo '<br />';
        //echo 'Step 3: ';
        //echo $recipe['step3'].'<br />';
        //echo '<br />';
        //echo '<br />';
        //echo '<a href="http://'.$recipe['reference'].'">'.$recipe['reference'].'</a>';  
        //echo '</li>';
        //echo '</ul>';


    }
}


?>
```

This is the php for grabbing the information from the database.

Comment: Is your actual question "Would I need to use a session id?"

Comment: @sircapsalot I would like to know if that is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Fetch the recipe `id` from the table along with the steps and either make the `Look` button a link (e.g. to `recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe['id']; ?>`) or keep it a form and add a hidden field: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $recipe['id']; ?> />"`. Depending on your form method (`get` or `post`), you can access the id as `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` in _recipe.php_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that all of your recipes have id numbers in your database. You could just use `$_GET` variables so that each 'look' button would be a link containing something like:

```
<?php

//Link part of message
echo "<a href='/recipies/detail.php?id=" . $recipe['id'] . "'>" . $recipe['name'] . "</a>";

?>
```

That way, the user could bookmark a recipe page or share the page with others easily. Then on the `details.php` page you just need to look in the database for a recipe with the specified id.

Comment: Thank you, my recipes do have an ID, I will give this a try. I'm new to this still so I will look into $_GET variables more.

Comment: I'm glad this solution works for you. Make sure to select the answer that best helped you (by clicking on the check below the answer rank number).

Answer (score 0):

Use the recipe id, instead of a session id -

first add `id` to your query

```
// add your `recipe`.`id` to your search query
SELECT DISTINCT `id`, `name`, `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, `image`, `reference`
    FROM `recipe` r
    INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
    ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
    WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (".$ingredient1.",".$ingredient2.",".$ingredient3.")
```

then put that id in your form action link -

```
    echo "<form action=\"recipe.php?id={$recipe['id']}\">";
```

and then on `recipe.php` you can get that `id` to use in your query

```
   $recipe_id = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['id']);
```